# Using a batch file to overwrite a zip archive

Tags: batch-file, compression, dropbox, 7-zip

I have a shared Dropbox file which I'll be updating often. Because it's a large file, I compress it to save space.

Because it's a shared file, I need to maintain the link.

I need to be able to constantly re-compress the updated file, so that my clients can always get the latest **compressed** version using the same link.

Also, can this be done using a batch file? What commands should I use?

Comment: If it is the same file name, perhaps dropbox will not need a new URL (as I doubt they check with checksum or other unique identifiers). Surely though, dropbox allows you to share a _folder_?

Answer (score 0):

**Dropbox**

As pointed out by @michael-nancarrow, Dropbox maintains the same URL for files and folders which are shared, regardless of updates/file changes, assuming the names and locations do not change.

So if your shared file is called *client_updates_latest.zip*, as long as the name and location for that file remains the same, your link will work. If you need different filenames (e.g. *client_updates_01-01.zip*, *client_updates_02-02.zip*) you should use just a shared folder (e.g. "Client Updates").

**Batch Files**

Regarding using a batch file, [using a command-line compression program such as 7za](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) (the CLI version of [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/)), you could have something as simple as e.g.:

```
 @REM Remove our old version of the latest client updates
 del "C:\Path\To\Dropbox\client_updates_latest.zip"

 @REM Make a new version of our latest client updates
 7za a "C:\Path\To\Dropbox\client_updates_latest.zip" "C:\Path\To\File\client_update.file"
```

If you do not intend to use a program such as *7za* (i.e. you have already made the archive file by hand), you can replace both lines with e.g.:

```
move /Y "C:\Path\To\Your\File\client_update_latest.zip" "C:\Path\To\Dropbox\client_updates_latest.zip"
```

The `/Y` option prevents you from being prompted to confirm overwriting any existing file.

**Notes**

- In the first example above, *7za* will make the archive given in the first argument while the second argument indicates a file that you wish to compress.
- For *7za*, the second argument can be a folder (so you can compress several files at once).
- The batch commands you use will depend highly on the program you use to compress your files. Some archiving utilities do not work from the command line.
- Besides the [del](https://www.computerhope.com/delhlp.htm) (delete) and [move](https://www.computerhope.com/movehlp.htm) commands, you may also be interested in [copy](https://www.computerhope.com/copyhlp.htm) and [rename](https://www.computerhope.com/renamehl.htm).
- System variables (such as %1) can be used to replace items in the script, [allowing you to specify e.g. your .zip name(s) at the command line when you run the batch file](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/num/percent1.htm).
- If you aren't already familiar with it, [Windows Task Scheduler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page) can be used to automatically run your batch file at particular times.